# Switch to TWM in Fedora 20

Tags: fedora, window-manager, twm

I want to use TWM without, say, GNOME or KDE or Xfce. Just plain TWM, no frills. I'm new to the whole desktop environment/window/display manager aspect so I'm not sure how I should go about setting this up.

Comment: Bravo! twm is still a fast, lightweight window manager with interesting concepts incorporated. Be sure to investigate doing your own menus, and modifying what mouseclicks on the background can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming you have `twm` installed (`yum install xorg-x11-twm`), create a shell script in `$HOME` called `.xinitrc`:

```
#!/bin/sh

twm
```

That's it.  I believe this must be executable (`chmod a+x .xinitrc`).  You will now be able to `startx` from the console and get twm (don't invoke this script yourself directly).  If you use a display manager (graphical login), it should use this as well, although I cannot promise.

See also `man xinit`.

Comment: Will any gnome/kde components be loaded still? I'm looking to reduce memory usage with this, too.

Comment: They're only loaded if you use them.

Comment: I tried this today, but to no avail. I'm using XDM as my display manager, and with that script (and the same code in .xsessions) nothing happens when I login, save for a frozen, centered mouse cursor. I can switch to other consoles though, however, so the system is not hanged. Any ideas? I wish this wasn't so hard, I'm almost tempted to just reinstall with the minimal install.

Comment: Unless you are really attached to the graphical login, I'd just remove that so you boot to console and then use `startx` -- I've posted an explanation for that here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164005/non-graphical-boot-with-systemd

Comment: ...also just noticed I had the shebang reversed (`!#/bin/sh` should have been `#!/bin/sh`; # before !, now edited correctly).  If you duplicated that mistake it would be a problem.