# Non-graphical boot with systemd

Tags: systemd

I want to boot to console instead of a GUI using `systemd`.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Open a terminal and (as root) run:

```
systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

or with `--force`

```
systemctl set-default -f multi-user.target
```

to overwrite any existing conflicting symlinks<sup>[1](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html)</sup>.

Double-check with:

```
systemctl get-default
```

Another way is to add the following parameter to your kernel boot line:

```
systemd.unit=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 9):

In `/etc/systemd/system` you'll find a [symlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link), `default.target`.  Currently this points to `/usr/lib/systemd/system/graphical.target` (you can see this with `readlink default.target`.

As root (or via sudo), delete the symlink and replace it:

```
rm default.target
ln -s /usr/lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target default.target
```

Double check that with `type default.target`.  It should say "symbolic link to...", not "*broken* symbolic link to..." in which case you typed the target wrong, start again.  Also double check you got the name right, `default.target` -- all this is important to having the system reboot properly.

You can now reboot and go to console instead of a display manager.  To change back to a GUI login, reverse the process above.

Answer (score 6):

`KDM` has [a bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=771188) where it will ignore the `multi-user.target` target when using `systemd`.

You still need to set the `multi-user.target` as mentioned in the answers above. But for some reason `KDE` will ignore that even when it is correctly set and still run at boot :/ .

Here is the work around that I found that eventually did the trick. Add the following to your kernel command line parameters:

```
systemd.mask=kdm.service
```

I edited `/etc/default/grub` and changed the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line to read as follows:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet systemd.mask=kdm.service"
```

After this change update `grub`:

```
update-grub
```

Now after a reboot the system displays a console login prompt rather than starting X and `KDE`.