# Why is my Debian jessie always in runlevel 5?

Tags: debian, systemd, init, runlevel

I have configured the lines in `/etc/inittab` as follows:

```
# The default runlevel.
id:2:initdefault:
```

But after logging in the output of `runlevel` is as follows:

```
N 5
```

So why am I in runlevel 5 instaed of 2?

---

**Note:** As an additionaly info here is `uname -a` output for my system

```
Linux d3bi4n 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-2 (2014-11-06) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and the output of `dpkg -S /sbin/init` is

```
systemd-sysv: /sbin/init
```

Comment: You are using SysVinit, right? What is the output of `dpkg -S /sbin/init`?

Comment: It's `systemd-sysv: /sbin/init`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> ```
> $ dpkg -S /sbin/init
> systemd-sysv: /sbin/init
> ```

Your init system is Systemd, not SysVinit. `/etc/inittab` is a configuration file of SysVinit, it is not used by Systemd. I presume you have this file because this is a jessie system which was upgraded from an earlier jessie or from wheezy with SysVinit.

Systemd doesn't exactly have a concept of runlevels, though it approximates them for compatibility with SysVinit. Systemd has “target units” instead. You can choose the boot-time target unit by setting the symbolic link `/etc/systemd/system/default.target`. See the [Systemd FAQ](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/FrequentlyAskedQuestions/) for more information.

If you don't want to use Systemd, install the [`sysvinit-core`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/sysvinit-core) package, which provides a traditional SysVinit (formerly in the `sysvinit` package, which in jessie is now a front for systemd). As of jessie, Debian defaults to Systemd but still supports SysVinit.

Comment: Your figured it out. I upgraded from wheezy and was not aware of jessie using systemd. I switched back to sysvinit (for now) and it works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Source:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/164028/120177 , http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html

Open a terminal and (as root) run:

```
systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

or with --force

```
systemctl set-default -f multi-user.target
```

to overwrite any existing conflicting symlinks1.

Double-check with:

```
systemctl get-default
```

Another way is to add the following parameter to your kernel boot line:

```
systemd.unit=multi-user.target
```

Comment: this is the same answer as http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/164028/120177 . But you forgot about link to http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html

Comment: Done. Added the sources.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably have runlevel 5 set in the kernel command line or arguments (look at your grub configuration):

You may override the default runlevel with kernel parameter. When the boot menu is displayed, select the edit option. Then locate the kernel line and append space and the desired runlevel number. E.g. "kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.30 root=/dev/sda2 ro 3" would boot to runlevel 3.

Answer (score 0):

I looking how to run under Debian 8 similar like use with `inittab` system:

```
1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty1

2:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty2

3:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty3

BPQ:2345:respawn:/home/bpq32/runbpq >/dev/tty4
```

where I have redirect output run program `runbpq` to `/dev/tty4`

but how to do this under Debian 8 with systemd ??

Best regards

Answer (score -1):

From: https://wiki.debian.org/RunLevel

**Default Debian installation does not make any difference between runlevels 2-5.**

Comment: @matthias Your understanding is correct. By default, Debian configures exactly the same services to run in runlevels 2, 3, 4 and 5. Nonetheless, the runlevel number is tracked; the `inittab` line should make runlevel 2 the default.