# Why does my script does not run in runlevel 0?

Tags: debian, systemd, shutdown, init-script

I made a script with following LSB header

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          updateservice
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $time $network $named $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $time $network $named $syslog
# Default-Start:
# Default-Stop:      0
# Short-Description: Update Service
# Description:       This script is meant to update and upgrade
#                    the system. It uses apt-get.
### END INIT INFO
```

placed it in `/etc/init.d` and created the links with `update-rc.d` and got the one  I wanted to have

```
 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 Nov 29 13:08 /etc/rc0.d/K01update.sh -> ../init.d/update.sh
```

.... but: The script ist not executed at shutdown. Why?

Running `/etc/init.d/update.sh stop` manuallly does exactly what I want, but it's not executed when shutting down. And, just as a fun fact, same script and configuration on a raspberry pi works just as expected.

You guys are the experts... anybody any idea?

PS: `uname -a` output:

```
Linux d3bi4n 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-2 (2014-11-06) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My init system is Systemd.

Comment: Releated (http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48973/execute-a-command-before-shutdown).

Comment: @DisplayName thanks, but I already saw this post and it does not fix my problem

Comment: Given http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170555/why-is-my-debian-jessie-always-in-runlevel-5 it turns out that you're running Systemd. So do you want to know how to run a shutdown-time script with Systemd, or do you want to switch back to SysVinit?

Comment: Hey @Gilles .. you are the man! 
Thanks for your post on the other question. I switched back to sysvinit for now. But I think about changing to systemd later (after doing some research).

Answer (score -1):

From your output :

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 Nov 29 13:08 /etc/rc0.d/K01update.sh -> ../init.d/update.sh
```

`K` in `K01update.sh` means killing process in 01th step when linux goes to zero runlevel! I don't have debian but as all of them are linux, In redhat linux you need to add a comment line like following to tell the `chkconfig` start or stop the service in these priorities!

```
# chkconfig: 2345 70 80
```

The first numbers are runlevels (2345), second one means starting priority (70), and the last one means stopping priority(80)!

But I have no idea about `update-rc.d` whether it need it or not!

Comment: Hey, due to the fact that the K scripts are run before the S scripts, starting a script in runlevel 0 has to be done in a K script (the last K script shuts down the system - after that nothing else will/can be executed ;)). So I configured my script in init.d as such that it will be executed if the parameter "stop" is used abd therefore the placement as K01 ...

Comment: `lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 17 Nov  5 07:28 S00killall -> ../init.d/killall`
`lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 14 Nov  5 07:28 S01halt -> ../init.d/halt` These are shutdown the system not last K.

Comment: Hey again, here is my content in `/etc/rc0.d`

Comment: Sorry, new try:
`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  14 Nov 29 13:08 K10halt -> ../init.d/halt`

Comment: I think the differences between your system and mine are coming from the different distros.

Comment: :)) Yes, I think there are large differences between them.

Comment: Debian doesn't use chkconfig comments, that's a Red Hat thing.

Comment: @Gilles, as I said I just talking about redhat not debian ;)